# How do I review questions where the user hasn't tried anything?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Ok, so I was reviewing this particular question and while I have encountered situations like this before, I was never sure how to act upon them.

Here is the question:

> Iam very new iOS and Xcode and phone gap i have made some sample application now i want to send it to my friend to see it in mobile how it works can any one say how to fetch that .ipa file and send it

Now, if we ignore the poor phrasing and punctuation, how do I review this question?

Is it appropiate to flag as `unclear what you're asking`? Or any other of the flags are more appropiate?

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: Too broad would fit as well.

Comment: Ok, so one of `unclear what you're asking` and `too broad`. Thanks!

Comment: Often also "no mcve". Or any fitting off-topic reason (not migration).